# How to check whether an element has an ID in pure javascript? And conditional statement problems

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

In the code below you may see a few problems ( or alot of problems ). First, I am assuming the sender element has an ID in the first line of my function. My console is full with errors as some of the divs calling this function don't have IDs in my html ( *in my actual website, this is a small reproduction of the problem* ). Do I have to give them ID's or can I have the function first check if they have IDs, and then proceed? Second problem is my if statement. It is always trying to check 3 parent elements up of every element calling this function! I have so many errors in the console because of this - how can I keep the same result of this function without generating those errors. For Instance, before checking the ID of 3 parent elements, can I first check to see if it even has 3 parent elements? My code is below and here is **JSBIN:** http://jsbin.com/somimoniva/1/edit

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id = "boxContainer">
      <div id = "box">
        <div id = "content">
          <p id = "contentParagraph" 
             onmouseover = "someFunction( this );">content stuff</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id = "otherStuff" onmouseover = "someFunction( this );">
      other stuff
    </div>

    <script>
      function someFunction( element ){
        var elementId = element.id;
        var elementInner = document.getElementById( elementId ).innerHTML;

        if( document.getElementById( elementId ).parentElement
        .parentElement.parentElement.id == 'boxContainer' ){
          document.getElementById( 'otherStuff' ).innerHTML = 'content was hovered';
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm not using jquery.

Comment: If you've already got the element involved in the event, why do you need to call `getElementById()` to fetch it again?

Comment: I guess i don't but is that causing the problem? Should i try i without this?

Comment: *" but is that causing the problem"* Of course. If the element doesn't have an ID you can't look it up by ID.

Comment: I'm really trying to fix this in my code but not working can you please just update my jsBin with the proper code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, the function of this 'application' can be simplified to the following script:

```
<script>
    function someFunction( element ){
        document.getElementById( 'otherStuff' ).innerHTML = 'content was hovered';
    }
</script>
```

As per [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ntvtbqLb/) fiddle.

You can even loose most of the `id`'s.

To answer your more specific question, you can test for an `id` first so that an error isn't thrown:

```
function hasId(element){
    return typeof element.id != 'undefined';
}
```

**Solution:**

How about altering your code to use the above method. Like so:

```
function someFunction( element ){
    var parent = element.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;

    if( hasId(parent) && parent.id == 'boxContainer' ){
        document.getElementById( 'otherStuff' ).innerHTML = 'content was hovered';
    }
}
```

This performs the check for an `id`, while also checking that the `id` is `"boxContainer"`. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ntvtbqLb/1/).

Comment: This is kind of hard to explain: I have alot of onmouseover events with different Ids, some with no Ids in my real program. I cant target just one ID for this reason. I think.

Comment: This answers the first half of my question. But my code is still trying to search for 3 parent Elements of every caller - which throws an error. any ideas?

Comment: @carb0nshel1 I've provided a workable solution above. As a general rule, having your application logic rely so heavily on markup structure is a bad idea. If you're just starting out then these kinds of muddles are good ones to learn from. Keep going with it, but don't be afraid of scrapping what you have and starting over.

Comment: sigh. I understand why you removed the onmouseover event from `otherStuff` but the whole point of the question was kind of for it to remain. I appreciate your effort, maybe my question isn't clear enough yet again. Sorry.

Comment: @carb0nshel1 on the contrary, the reason the otherStuff event got removed is clearly because the 'whole point' of the question was not expressed. Perhaps you should try telling us what you want the application to actually do. We are not mind readers.

Comment: This answer has helped me find the solution. Thank you.

Comment: @carb0nshel1 No problem - glad it has helped.

Answer (score 9):

The suggested answer is wrong regarding checking for an element's id:

```
typeof element.id != 'undefined';
```

`element.id` will return an empty string, if the DOM element has no id specified (and is thereby never 'undefined').
To check if an element has an id specified, you can do:

```
element.hasAttribute('id')
```

Or:

```
element.hasOwnProperty('id')
```

Or even:

```
element.getAttribute('id') !== null
```